# can't connect with mysql on company network

Tags: mysql

I have built an application in vb.net that needs to connect to a mysql database. This all works fine from my own network and several other home networks.

But if i want to use the application on my company's network, i get the error

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

I thought that this is caused by the firewall of the network.
But I used the "automatic update" option and I publish the application on a online server. This works fine on my company's network.

So the application can download the updates from the network, but can't connect to the mysql server. What could cause this issue?

Comment: You companies network is most likely set up differently than your home network. Talk with your company and get information from them.

Answer (score 1):

The most common situation that would cause this is selective egress filtering. Specifically, the firewall is most likely only allowing HTTP/HTTPS port connections out.

Try changing mysql to listen on 443, then try again using 443 instead. The firewall may allow the traffic since it is using 443 like web traffic instead of 3306 (mysql default).

Comment: When i use this connectionstring: Dim myConnectionString As String = "Server=(....);Port=443;Database=(...);Uid=(....);Pwd=(...);" I can't connect at home. Isn't this the right connectionstring?

Comment: I've talked to the IT department and it was indeed the TCP port. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing it locally, its because you need to whitelist the IP that you're CURRENTLY on.

On live sites, the IP of the server doesn't change. So you use that IP with the correct permissions to allow mysql to work.

So basically, figure out where your allowed IP's to talk to the DB are, find your local ip, and modify. Incorrect ports can be a problem also

Comment: I've used a "%" to allow all IP-addresses. This works for all "home"-networks i've been testing on.

Comment: not a good idea! you dont want anyone to be able to modify or view your DB. If the IP is indeed whitelisted, then your firewall can be making the connections timeout

Comment: The users of the application need to fill the database. They need to do this on different locations, so I have to do it this way, right?

Comment: Nope! If your users are viewing it on a website then the IP of it wont change. The DB will talk to the page using the servers IP not your connection IP.